# AVERAGEIFS excluding cells that contain specified text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate average leverage levels for years 2010-2017 with `AVERAGEIFS`, but would want to exclude Infrastructure sector.

Here's a formula that includes all sectors (simplified by removing the $-signs):

```
=AVERAGEIFS(V186:V891,J186:J891,H164)
```

V: leverage, J: year, H: year next to the formula cell

I tried doing this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(V186:V891,J186:J891,H165,K186:K891,{"Communication","Consumer Discretionary","Consumer Staples","Energy","Financials","Healthcare","Industrials","Materials","Other","Technology","Utilities"})
```

K: sectors

My try to include all other sectors than Infrastructure doesn't work for some reason, because the average I get for e.g. year 2012 is 3.5 with the 1st formula, and 3.1 with the 2nd, although there're no Infrastructure deals that year. Additionally, some years return `#DIV/0!`.

I also tried to search for a way to write the formula that excludes Infra deals in a simpler way, but didn't find anything. I'm thinking something like this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(V186:V891,J186:J891,H164,K186:K891,NOT("Infrastructure"))
```

Question summarized: how could I calculate the average leverage level for each year, excluding infra deals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is almost there with this one:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(V186:V891,J186:J891,H164,K186:K891,NOT("Infrastructure"))
```

I haven't tested this, but have a go with it, it should exclude Infrastructure.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(V186:V891,J186:J891,H164,K186:K891,"<>"&"Infrastructure"))
```

<> is often used in Excel formulas as it means 'not equals'.

Thanks,
Dom

Comment: Of course the answer is as simple as that! And I wasted so much time on this... But hey, thanks a million!

Comment: No worries, we've all been there.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is just:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(V186:V891,J186:J891,H164,K186:K891,"<>Infrastructure")
```